# Which type of equation to use in the curve fitting tool in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, curve, sigmoid

I have some data points and I want to fit a custom equation to that curve. The data are as follows:

```
-20.5   -632.8475722
-19.5   -633.3214772
-18.5   -646.6016049
-17.5   -683.4637841
-16.5   -649.8121364
-15.5   -616.4297769
-14.5   -609.9639983
-13.5   -534.5818772
-12.5   -532.2347152
-11.5   -452.9222271
-10.5   -427.6525318
-9.5    -380.3710984
-8.5    -322.5516672
-7.5    -294.1208624
-6.5    -222.1675481
-5.5    -202.2179342
-4.5    -165.122709
-3.5    -134.827559
-2.5    -88.25392126
-1.5    -66.0446787
-0.5    -52.03853651
0.5 -35.01795243
1.5 -18.27307888
2.5 4.200002613
3.5 31.46742774
4.5 65.02174186
5.5 113.4098161
6.5 132.8355363
7.5 115.0080076
8.5 124.3832919
```

It looks to me like a sigmoidal-type function, but I cannot find the correct custom-type equation to fit the data. I have tried the following, but it misses the upper values. Which type of equation can I use?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Fitting a specific function is only useful if you have a model, if you know that the function is supposed to match reality. If the fit is poor, it is because your model of reality is wrong, or because of noise or bias in the measurements. Changing your model would be the wrong approach to science at that point, you need to establish it before you start measuring. If you don’t have a model, and just want to fit any function to your data, try fitting a polynomial. Start with a 3rd order one, and increase the order until you’re satisfied with the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple linear fitting (blue) is better than your logistic fitting (lime) :

[image]

This is due to the model y(x)=a / (1 + exp(b * x) + c)

For this model y(x) tends to 0 for large x which is not consistent with the data : Obviously y(x) is larger than 0 for large x.

Instead of the three parameters logistic function, try the four parameters logistic function : y(x) = K + a / ( 1 + exp(b * x) + c)

Even more, the shape of the points makes think to a double logistic y(x) = K + a / (1 + exp(b * x) + c) + A / (1 + exp(B * x) + C) but too many parameters makes difficult the non-linear fitting process.

Or on an equivalent form of double logistic function (written with different symbols) :

[image]

Nevertheless I agree with a large part of the comment from Cris Luengo to the main question.